# RxSwift not working with UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, rx-swift

I am working on RxSwift and started creating few basic. I have added new button however with rx_tap subscribe not working for button action. Below is my code, please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 66, width: 100, height: 21))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    button.rx_tap
        .subscribe { [weak self] x in
            self!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subscription is cancelled immediately because of the scope of your `DisposeBag`. It is created, then goes out of scope and immediately deallocated. You need to retain your bag somewhere. If you are using a view controller or something like that, you can create a property there and assign it to that.

Comment: Thanks Dima, can you please explain with sample code for the same, that will be really great help

Comment: move `let disposeBag = DisposeBag()` out of that function and as a property declaration in the containing class. Just doing that will make the rest of your code work.

Comment: Wow it works like a charms, thanks for the much help, I will always be thankful, I am very new to RxSwift and its causing me confusion a lot.